# What can be causing a delay in database fetch in Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am fetching 5000 rows each round trip via a JDBC call (total rows around 10 million). The rows are not wide at all, less than 100 chars. The queries take a long time to run which is fine, however once the queries complete, the fetch works, but sometimes I must wait 15 minutes between fetch calls...

Running queries was always taking a long time but fetches used to be blazingly fast in the same database -- but suddenly we see these massive delays between fetches. This is being experienced by multiple clients all of a sudden so I know it isn't my machine.

My question is what could be the possible cause of this issue? Could it be running out of space or would it be some sort of hardware issue? Is it too many concurrent users?

Any thoughts would be appreciated

JDBC code sample:

```
   // Netezza Source Connection
    sourceConnection = ConnectionFactory.connection(sourceProfile);
    sourceStatement = sourceConnection.createStatement();
    sourceStatement.setFetchSize(5000);
    sourceResultSet = sourceStatement.executeQuery(sourceQuery);

   // Synapse Target Connection
    targetConnection = ConnectionFactory.connection(targetProfile);
    targetStatement = targetConnection.createStatement();
    targetStatement.setFetchSize(5000);
    targetResultSet = targetStatement.executeQuery(targetQuery);

    boolean sourceNotEOF = readSource(sourceResultSet);
    boolean targetNotEOF = readTarget(targetResultSet);

    while(sourceNotEOF && targetNotEOF) {

        if(_sourceKey.compareTo(_targetKey) < 0) {
            // Source key mismatch
            sourceNotEOF = readSource(sourceResultSet);
        }
        else if(_sourceKey.compareTo(_targetKey) > 0) {
            // Target key mismatch
             targetNotEOF = readTarget(targetResultSet);
        }
        else {
            if(_targetHash.compareTo(_sourceHash) <> 0) {
                // Keys match but hash does not
            }
            else{
                // Perfect match, key and hash
            }

            sourceNotEOF = readSource(sourceResultSet);
            targetNotEOF = readTarget(targetResultSet);
        }
    }

    while(sourceNotEOF && threshold > 0) {
            // Source key mismatch
            sourceNotEOF = readSource(sourceResultSet);
    }

    while(targetNotEOF && threshold > 0) {
            // Target key mismatch
             targetNotEOF = readTarget(targetResultSet);
    }
```

It gets stuck on readTarget function. Synapse eventually returns after resultSet.next() is called, however sometimes it takes 30 minutes.

```
private final boolean readSource(ResultSet resultSet) throws Throwable {
    boolean result = resultSet.next();
    if(result) {
        _sourceKey = resultSet.getString("IDENTIFIER");
        _sourceHash = resultSet.getString("HASH_VALUE");
    }
    return result;
}

private final boolean readTarget(ResultSet resultSet) throws Throwable {
    boolean result = resultSet.next();
    if(result) {
        _targetKey = resultSet.getString("IDENTIFIER");
        _targetHash = resultSet.getString("HASH_VALUE");
    }
    return result;
}
```

The query simply compares all the rows in both tables like so:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Netezza Query
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
    TRIM(COALESCE(CAST(MYTABLE.COLUMN5 AS VARCHAR(20)), '')) || '  |  ' ||
    TRIM(COALESCE(MYTABLE.COLUMN6, '')) AS IDENTIFIER,
    RAWTOHEX(HASH(
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST(MYTABLE.COLUMN0 AS VARCHAR(20)), '')) ||
      TRIM(COALESCE(TO_CHAR(MYTABLE.COLUMN1, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), '')) ||
      TRIM(COALESCE(TO_CHAR(MYTABLE.COLUMN2, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), '')) ||
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST(MYTABLE.COLUMN3 AS VARCHAR(20)), '')) ||
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST(MYTABLE.COLUMN4 AS VARCHAR(20)), '')) ||
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST(MYTABLE.COLUMN5 AS VARCHAR(20)), '')) ||
      TRIM(COALESCE(MYTABLE.COLUMN6, '')) ||
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST(MYTABLE.COLUMN7 AS VARCHAR(20)), ''))
    , 0)) AS HASH_VALUE
FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
ORDER BY IDENTIFIER, HASH_VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Synapse Query
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
    TRIM(COALESCE(CAST([MYTABLE].[COLUMN5] AS VARCHAR(20)), '')) + '  |  ' +
    TRIM(COALESCE([MYTABLE].[COLUMN6], '')) AS IDENTIFIER,
    HASHBYTES ('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST([MYTABLE].[COLUMN0] AS VARCHAR(20)), '')) +
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST(FORMAT([MYTABLE].[COLUMN1], 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') AS VARCHAR(14)), '')) +
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST(FORMAT([MYTABLE].[COLUMN2], 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') AS VARCHAR(14)), '')) +
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST([MYTABLE].[COLUMN3] AS VARCHAR(20)), '')) +
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST([MYTABLE].[COLUMN4] AS VARCHAR(20)), '')) +
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST([MYTABLE].[COLUMN5] AS VARCHAR(20)), '')) +
      TRIM(COALESCE([MYTABLE].[COLUMN6], '')) +
      TRIM(COALESCE(CAST([MYTABLE].[COLUMN7] AS VARCHAR(20)), ''))
    )) AS HASH_VALUE
FROM [MYSCHEMA].[MYTABLE]
ORDER BY IDENTIFIER, HASH_VALUE
```

I ran the following and see an error for the session

```
select details from sys.dm_pdw_errors where session_id = 'SID173529'

details
  Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Common.ErrorHandling.ActionCancelledException: 
  Query Cancelled. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Common.ErrorHandling.ActionCancelledException: 
  Cancel occurred while reading from dataReader. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException[0:0]: A severe error occurred on the current command.  
  The results, if any, should be discarded.  Operation cancelled by user.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, 
  Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, 
  Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, 
  SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)     
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)     
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Distributor.SqlDataReaderResultSet.DoRead()     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Distributor.SqlDataReaderResultSet.Read()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Distributor.DistributedResultSetWithPrefetch.Read()     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Tds.PdwResultSet.SendRows(IResultSet rs)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Tds.PdwResultSet.ProcessResultSet(IResultSet rs, ProcessResultSetOption processOption)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Tds.TdsServiceClient.ProcessResultSet(IResultSet rs, Boolean isInsideTryBlock)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Tds.TdsServiceClient.ProcessException(Exception exception, Boolean topLevelCall)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Tds.TdsServiceClient.ProcessResultSet(IResultSet rs, Boolean isInsideTryBlock)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Executables.ReturnExecutable.HandleResult(ISessionContext session, IDistributionResult result)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Executables.SqlExecutable.TransactionalWork.ExecuteUnitOfWorkForControlNode()     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Executables.SqlExecutable.ExecuteWork(TransactionScopeOption option, Action callback)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Executables.SqlExecutable.OnExecute(ISessionContext sessionContext)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Executables.AbstractExecutable`1.Execute(ISessionContext session)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Executables.ExecutableProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<ExecuteExecutable>b__0(IList`1 propagationTokens)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Executables.ExecutableProcessor.ExecuteActionInDistributedTransactions(Int32 transactionsCount, Action`1 action, IList`1 propagationTokens)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Executables.ExecutableProcessor.ExecuteExecutable(EngineExecutionPlan plan, IExecutable executable, ExecutionContext context)     
  at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()     
  at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Executables.ExecutableProcessor.ExecutePlan(EngineExecutionPlan plan, ExecutionContext context)     
  at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()     
  at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Executables.ExecutableProcessor.RunExecutables(EngineExecutionPlan plan, IList`1 executables)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Processors.DistributedQueryProcessor.ExecuteDistributedPlan()     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Engine.Utils.EventUtils.
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code that you're using?  We do not need to see secure server names or passwords, just representative code.  I find the `spark.read.synapsesql` read API from Spark notebooks pretty good to be honest.  With dedicated SQL pools you always need to consider what DWU it is running at, what resource class is associated with the user and what is the table distribution (round robin, hash, replicate) and indexing (clustered columnstore, heap, clustered index).  Blocking could play a role too.

Comment: you mean my jdbc code? or the query?   The code is definitely not blocking as this was blazingly fast before ... i never changed the code.... I am comparing two different databases (netezza and synapse) for equality based on a hash value of all columns on the same table

Comment: It appears when the results that are cached are not returned to the client for whatever reason and the client machine issues a cancel, it causes synapse to crash and impairs the entire database pool (even when the session has been cancelled) Problem is we do not know how to restore the database back to a stable state (we usually wait hours and it fixes itself)

Comment: i will escalate to Microsoft and update this post once I do. An errant query should not destabilize the entire pool but in this case it appears to be doing so as there is no other active sessions and yet the whole box is hanging because of this one error pasted above

Comment: FORMAT does not have a great reputation for performance so it may be worth trying CONVERT with a format switch (like 113, 114 etc) to see if that helps.  It’s unlikely this is the entire cause of your issue though.

Comment: Thanks. Good thing is it appears this query is the source of all problems (i actually forgot to add a distribution column in the join which i left out in example) so it is reproducible by simply leaving out that column, allowing the query to run (albeit inefficiently).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved ... we needed to run an UPDATE STATISTICS on every table that was involved in the query and the issue went away